# How to transfer ether from sender account to a given account with specific value parameter -- Smart Contract

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am writing a contract where I want to transfer money to an account address passed to a function in the contract. I take three-parameter from, to, and value. Also, I added a screenshot to better understand.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qztcr.png)

```
contract Transaction{
    
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    
    event Transfer(address buyer, address seller,uint value);
    


    function _transfer(address _from, address payable _to, uint256 _value) internal {
        require(balances[_from] >= _value, "Insufficient balance");
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        _to.transfer(_value);
    }

   

    function transfer(address _from,address payable _to, uint256 _value) external payable returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Error:**

transact to Transaction. transfer errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
The reason provided by the contract: "Insufficient balance".
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Please Help Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transfer money you just need the receiving address the from address is msg.sender and value is msg.value which should be mention in value field under Gas Limit field , the correct function is as follow:

```
 function transfer(address payable _to) external payable returns (bool) {
        _to.transfer( msg.value);
        return true;
    }
```

P.S: in case of want to create Token , you should initiate total supply for contract and better to follow ERC20 standard